# How to get code coverage badge for azure pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, code-coverage, azure-pipelines

I have my github project configured for automated builds in Azure Pipelines. Under "Pipelines/Builds/" I can click on "..." and select "Status badge".

Inside pipelines, code coverage is already measured: I can select a specific build, and go to the tab "Code coverage". However, I can't find any link to the coverage badge. Is it provided by Azure Devops? Or is there any free tool that integrates with Azure Devops to provide this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get a coverage badge for Azure Pipelines by using shields.io:

1. go to https://shields.io/category/coverage
2. select Azure Devops coverage
3. As the website instructs, you need to find out `organization`,
   `project` and `definition id`. Head to the Azure pipelines, and open
   the view where you can see the history of builds for your project. The URL will contain all 3 values, e.g. dev.azure.com/`ikamenshchikov`/`flynt`/_build?definitionId=`1`
4. enter the values you have found in Azure into shields.io blank
   fields, and click Copy Badge URL to get an URL to the image. You will get an URL like  e.g. `https://img.shields.io/azure-devops/coverage/ikamenshchikov/flynt/1`.
5. now you can use this url to add the shield to e.g. your github
   `README.md`. Add the text
   `![Coverage](https://img.shields.io/azure-devops/coverage/ikamenshchikov/flynt/1)`

Comment: is not the same i posted ?

Comment: is detailed. Actually you have hinted at correct things.

Comment: I presume using sheilds.io only really applies if the Azure DevOps projects are publicly available. For closed-source or corporate projects I don't see how shields.io would have access.